# return NotFound() Web Api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Preciso que se o retorno do `Get` do `controller` abaixo for `null` ele retorne uma mensagem específica, onde tem `return NotFound()`, mas não tá funcionando como esperado e tentei implementar separadamente mas sempre dá **erro**.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
[ActionName("GetCNPJCPF")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCNPJCPF(string cnpj_cpf)
{
     pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.OfType<pessoa>()
                       .Where(p => p.cpf_cnpj == cnpj_cpf).FirstOrDefault();
     if (pessoa == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }
     return Ok(pessoa);
}
```

se ele não encontra simplesmente da erro **HTTP 404**

Comment: Ela já vem nativa quando criamos um Controller pelo wizard! Tentei implementar pelo **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139621/how-do-i-return-notfound-ihttpactionresult-with-an-error-message-or-exception**, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: não entendi o seu problema. `ApiController.NotFound` cria uma resposta 404, que é o que você retorna quando `pessoa` é nulo.

Comment: @mercador , preciso que ele retorne uma mensagem , ex. Nenhum registro encontrado, porque quando consulto por um ajax ele aparece como erro por causa da página 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar isso:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Qualquer objeto");
```

Comment: funcionou blz, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Você tera que criar sua mensagem personalizada a parte se quiser que ele a retorne.
[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139621/how-do-i-return-notfound-ihttpactionresult-with-an-error-message-or-exception) explica como fazer

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
return NotFound("Sua mensagem aqui");
```

Saída no navegador "Arquivo não foi encontrado ..."